# How to call read() after cin?

Tags: c++, input, cin

I have an application in which I should use **read()** from **unistd.h** to get the date from input, e.g.:

> 100 200 300 400 500

And I'm using this code:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
char* buffer = new char[100];
read(0, buffer, 100);
```

But when I put my line in console, it can't make **cin** for `100` and `200`, and then **read()** for `300 400 500`.
My goal is to put `100 200 300 400 500` as one line and press **enter** once.
So, how can I fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: How would you feel about using `std::string` instead of `char[]`?

Comment: @Beta I have a task to make my program faster, so use char*

Comment: @Artem: Have you proved that string is too slow (i.e. benchmarking)?

Comment: @Beta I don't really know this, but in the task even 0.01s is valuable

Comment: @Artem: Also, why are you forced to use `read` versus something like `cin.read`? Edit [Like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c34b22d734078100)

Comment: @Beta Because I've read that read() is faster thab cin :)

Comment: "I should use read()" No, you should not. "I've read that read() is faster" Don't believe everything you read.

Comment: @Coder Did you see any benchmarks to prove this claim?  If not, did you do any testing, such as obtaining a `clock_t` before and after calling `cin.read()`, and obtaining one before and after calling `unistd.h`'s `read()`?  Furthermore, do you know that this specifically is your program's biggest bottleneck?  (If it's not, you're not going to see a major difference.)

Comment: You are talking about *keyboard input*. If the difference between `cin` and `read` is holding you back, then you must have very fast hands.

Answer (score 0):

use string instead of int ; and read the hole line with getline

string a;
getline(cin, a);

Comment: I need ro make a very fast program

Comment: @Artem: Until you show that a straightforward solution is too slow, don't perform a premature optimization.

Comment: I really need to get the first number from the input line before the readimg part after it and the live is given only once

Answer (score 0):

You can use getline function like below to read the entire line at once.

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout

char input[100];
cin.getline(input, 100);
```